# Multiple render in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, pokeapi

I'm making a Pokedex app with React and I have displayed all of the names of the Pokemon. The problem is that it is multiple rendering and I cant figure out where. Some render twice while others render 3 times. My developer console is also giving me a unique key prop error. I would also like to get rid of the async and await. I've looked through the other questions and cant find the answer either.

Below is a snippet of the running code as is now.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {

  const [allPokemon, setAllPokemon] = useState([])
  const [loadMore, setLoadMore] = useState('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=151')
  const getAllPokemon = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(loadMore)
    const data = await response.json()

    setLoadMore(data.next) //loads next 151 pokemon

    const pokemonDetails = (result) => { //gets pokemon details from object
      result.forEach( async (pokemon) => {
        const response = await fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemon.name}`)
        const data = await response.json()

        setAllPokemon(currentList => [...currentList, data])
        allPokemon.push(data)
      })
    }
    pokemonDetails(data.results)
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    getAllPokemon()
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
    <div className="app-container">
      <h1>POKEDEX-APP</h1>
      <div className='pokemon-container'>
        <div className='all-containers'>
          {allPokemon.map(pokemon => <li>{pokemon.name}</li>)}
        </div>
        <button className='load-more'>Load More</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What's wrong with the `async`/`await`? It's required to fetch data when using `fetch`, unless you want to uses Promise callbacks: `fetch("url").then(res => res.json()).then(data => setLoadMore(data.next))`

Comment: For the key error, every list item needs a unique `key` prop. You should set it on your `<li key={pokemon.name}` (assuming `.name` is unique in the list)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider three things :

**First :**

Do not use `async` function as the callback of `forEach`. ([see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#description))

---

**Second:**

Change `getAllPokemon` body like this (update the states at the end of the function body):

```
const getAllPokemon = async () => {
  const response = await fetch(loadMore);
  const data = await response.json();
  
  let newPokemonDetails = [];
  for (let index = 0; index < data.results.length; index++) {
    const response = 
     await fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${data.results[index].name}`);
    const detailData = await response.json();
    newPokemonDetails.push(detailData);
  }
  
  setAllPokemon([...allPokemon, ...newPokemonDetails]);
  setLoadMore(data.next);
}
```

---

**Third:**

if each `pokemon` item has its own unique `id`, use that `id` as `key` prop of `li`. Otherwise use `index` of `map` at least:

```
{allPokemon.map((pokemon, index) => <li key={index}>{pokemon.name}</li>)}
//or if pokemons have id 
//<li key={pokemon.id}>{pokemon.name}</li>
```

---

**PS:**

If you don't want to use `async-await` statement, change `getAllPokemon` like this (in a simple form) :

```
const getAllPokemon = () => {
  fetch(loadMore)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      let newPokemonDetailPromiseList = [];
      data.results.forEach(item => {
        newPokemonDetailPromiseList.push(fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${item.name}`));
      });

      Promise.all(newPokemonDetailPromiseList)
        .then(res => {
          const jsonList = [];
          res.forEach(item => jsonList.push(item.json()));
          Promise.all(jsonList)
            .then(newPokemonDetails => {
              setAllPokemon([...allPokemon, ...newPokemonDetails]);
              setLoadMore(data.next);
            })
        })

    })
}
```

You can read more about `Promise.all()` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).